# Laravel - Store data temporary

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store data temporary and print in some other pages. The selected data lives only until I refresh the page. How can I fix it ? Thank you.

**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
{!! Form::select('first_name', $firstNames) !!}
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**DashboardController.php**

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{

    $this->data['online_users'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('last_activity','desc')->limit(10)->get();
    $this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');
    $request->session()->put('first_name', input::get('first_name'));
    $this->data['active'] = '';
    return view('dashboard.index',$this->data); 

}
```

**Echo**

```
<p>{{Session::get('first_name')}}</p>
```

Comment: Hi. Do you suggest to move the codes from DashboardController.php to rutes.php with a proper action ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use session variable to persist data across pages

> Page 1

```
{{Session::put('firstName','John')}}
```

> Page 2

```
{{Session::get('firstName')}}
```

So Try this

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{

$this->data['online_users'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('last_activity','desc')->limit(10)->get();
$this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');
\Session::put('first_name', $request->get('first_name'));
$this->data['active'] = '';
return view('dashboard.index',$this->data); 

}
```

> Add your routes to the web middleware to use sessions!

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['web']],function(){

 Route::get('myroute','DashboardController@getIndex');

});
```

See more about laravel sessions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session)

Comment: I tried this method for a week but could not make it work.

Comment: Umm. let me help you with it. Can you share the code?

Comment: Hi. I revised the question for you. Please take a look

Comment: I have just tried your updated code and returned NULL. Nothing stored.

Comment: Okay, make sure the routes are in web middleware!! Sessions only work in under web middleware!

check the updated code!

Comment: Thank you very much. This can work but I am getting this error **ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class web does not exist** Any idea ?

Comment: what version of larvel are you using.

Comment: It is Laravel 5.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131047/discussion-between-rahul-ravindran-and-selim).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `compact('data')` with `$data`

Comment: I tried this now. I am getting **Undefined variable: data** error

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{
  $data['online_users'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('last_activity','desc')->limit(10)->get();
  $data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');
  $data['first_name'] = input::get('first_name');
  $data['active'] = '';
  return view('dashboard.index')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Get on view like this

```
<p>{{ $data['first_name'] }}</p>
```

Comment: I am getting **Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'** error

Comment: Yes exactly the same. Copy and paste.

Comment: I tried. Now I am getting **Undefined index: first_name**

Comment: Check again sorry for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131032/discussion-between-komal-and-selim).

Answer (score 0):

For store session :- 
session(['first_name' => $request->get('first_name')])

For getting session value :- 
session('first_name')